# How to connect to a registered Node (Erlang) and use it from another erlang application

Tags: linux, network-programming, functional-programming, erlang, erlang-otp

I have a node started on

erl -name n1@198.XXX.X.XX -setcookie somecookie

(n1@198.XXX.X.XX)>

but then I have another erlang application in which I have a module where I want to use the node that I have just registered  (n1@198.XXX.X.XX).
I tried to do do directly from code net_adm:ping(n1@198.XXX.X.XX). and I get a pang. I can see that net_adm:names(). returns in the tuple all the registered and living nodes.{ok [{node, 999}],[{n1,9993}],[{theappnode, 8383}]}

I need a way to connect to n1, and then use to to ping another remote node with rpc, something like

conn = connect to node (n1)
and then do the rpc... 
these all from the module code of another erlang application....
Is the above possible?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your other node wasn't started with the same cookie. You have two solutions:

1. Start the other node with the same cookie

   ```
   erl -name otherapp -setcookie some cookie
   1> net_adm:ping('n1@198.X.X.X').
   pong
   ```
2. Start the other node and tell it what is the cookie of the n1 node.

   ```
   erl -name otherapp
   1> net_adm:ping('n1@198.X.X.X').
   pang
   2> erlang:set_cookie('n1@198.X.X.X', 'somecookie').
   true
   3> net_adm:ping('n1@198.X.X.X').
   pong
   ```

You cannot mix short names and long names (-sname and -name) in a distributed cluster.

Comment: I do not think you understand me or maybe I did not specified more things. I will edit the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187288/how-to-connect-to-a-registered-node-erlang-and-use-it-from-ejabberd